# Where did this user's rep go?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-graph

I'm looking at this brand new mod, [Stephane Martin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245505/st%C3%A9phane-martin?tab=summary), who answered one of my own questions, earning +45 rep in the process. So I expect him to be at 146 rep. But he is now at 143 rep. No downvotes or other rep changes. Looking at his rep graph, his rep stays at 146. It seems like he could have downvoted 3 answers, but his graph should respond by slightly going down to 143.

[image: 143 reputation]

The line on the graph is straight and stays at 146. So my question is, where is his missing 3 rep?

Before Oded goes [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), here's the image proving that the top says `146` not `143`:

[image: Graph]

Comment: It's probably caching.

Comment: I don't see that. I see 143 in the top of the graph. http://i.stack.imgur.com/U2AKk.png

Comment: @Oded - if you hover over the right hand end of the graph the tooltip does, in fact, say 146.

Comment: @ChrisF - no repro. At the right most the tooltip says 143 for me. You may be hitting a different server where the caching is different.

Comment: @Oded, your graph is different then the one ChrisF and I are seeing perhaps.

Comment: I can see what you guys are seeing when looking as an anonymous user.

Comment: @Oded of course you do :D did you forget you have a diamond? :)

Comment: Oded is too proud too notice. :-0 All he does is retag every feature-request and bug

Comment: And, just btw, Stéphane is not a brand new mod :)

Comment: He's using google chrome. One could easily fake that with dev tools.

Comment: Who's he here??

Comment: @warspyking ???

Comment: @nicael I'm not accusing anyone of anything, I'm just saying how easy it would be for OP to fake the "repro".

Comment: @warspyking That'd be relatively pointless and easily disprovable. No need to insinuate that someone's faking a bug report.

Comment: @PythonMaster Stéphane works for SE. He's one of our designers.

Comment: @Oded why status-completed? As far as I can tell, nothing has been fixed or changed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because if the graph would say 143, it would have to show where those 3 reps have gone, but it doesn't because the downvotes are private and can be seen only by moderators and the owner of that profile.

Oded is an employee, he has a diamond, so he can see where the downvotes have affected the rep of Stéphane Martin. The screenshot he posted:

> [image]

You see those "falls" of rep in March? These are private downvotes. *You* can't see them:

> [image]

Not only this new graph behaves this way to hide the downvotes, this is also the default old behaviour of the rep tab:

> [image]

Comment: That works for me! I'll upvote tomorrow... I'm out of votes

Comment: @Python lol "works for me" :)

Comment: Interesting. If this is the case then the new design is going to let mods see more than they can now.

Comment: @ChrisF I think only devs can see downvotes, so don't build your hopes too high. :-)

Comment: @Chris wait, mods really can't see downvotes?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I wasn't getting my hope up. If anything I was pointing out a potential flaw in the new design.

Comment: @nicael - we really can't. How many times have we told people this? The only thing we can see is voting *trends*.